# Show that $~X_n~:~n\ge 0~$ is a Markov chain.

Tags: markov-chains

> Consider a communication system which transmits the two digits $~0~$and$~1~$ through several stages. Let $~X_0~$ be the digit transmitted initially (leaving) $~0^{\text{th}}~$ stage and $~X_n~,~n\ge 1~$ be the digit leaving the $~n^{\text{th}}~$ stage. At every stage there is a constant probability$~q~$that the digit which enters is transmitted unchanged and the probability$~p~$other wise with $~p+q=1~$. ***Show that $~X_n~:~n\ge 0~$ is a Markov chain***.

As I am a newcomer in this session, I have no idea how to proceed. Any help in this matter is really appreciable. Thank You.

**Note:** Please give a complete solution, so that it will help me to solve the similar problems in future.

Comment: Since the transition probabilities are constant, the distribution of $X_n$ is independent of the past states $X_{n-1},...,X_{0}$, thus it is a markov chain

Comment: In the definition of $X_n$, is all we care about the digit ($0$ or $1$), or also the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ "stage"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood the question correctly, but I take it that
$$
X_n=\cases{X_{n-1}& with probability $\ q\ $, or\\
           1-X_{n-1} & with probability $\ p=1-q\ $.}
$$
If that's the case, then
\begin{align}
P\left(\left.X_n=b_n\right|X_{n-1}=b_{n-1},\right.&\left. X_{n-2}=b_{n-2},\dots,X_0=b_0\right)\\
&=\cases{q&if $\ b_n=b_{n-1}\ $, or\\
1-q& if $\ b_n\ne b_{n-1}\ $.}\\
&= P\left(\left.X_n=b_n\right|X_{n-1}=b_{n-1}\right)\ ,
\end{align}
which is the condition needed for $\ X_n\ $ to be a Markov chain.  The state of the chain at stage $\ n\ $ being $\ X_n\ $, with two possible values $0$ and $1$, it's a two-state chain with transition matrix
$$
\pmatrix{q&1-q\\
         1-q& q}\ .
$$

Comment: Sorry for the  late response @lonzaleggiera . The fact is that form another source I found that the  transition matrix for this case is $$\pmatrix{1-q&q\\
         q& 1-q}\ .$$

Comment: I can't see how that would be the transition matrix for the process as you've described it.  In your question, you define the probability $\ q\ $ as the probability "that the digit which enters is transmitted unchanged"—i.e. the probability the next state (the bit transmitted) is $\ 0\ $ given that the current state (the bit that  had entered) was $\ 0\ $, namely $\ p_{00}\ $, is $\ q\ $, and the probability the next state  is $\ 1\ $ given that the current state was $\ \ 1$, namely $\ p_{11}\ $, is also $\ q\ $.

Comment: Are you sure that your "other source" is using *precisely* the same definitions as the ones you've given here?

Comment: Yes, it is. @lonzaleggiera